# Notepad++ macro to replace in VB scripts variable assignments by the value of each assigned variable

Tags: regex, macros, notepad++

I've many files with VB script with many variables and I would like to replace all variable with their value by macro.

For example:

```
label1.text = "Fan"
label2.text = "Close"
label3.text = "Open"
ledfan.tag = label1.text
led2.tag = label2.text
led3.tag = label3.text
```

Into:

```
ledfan = "Fan"
led2 = "Close"
led3 = "Open"
```

I've tried to do that with macros, but I have the problem that the command Ctrl+C is not recorded into the macro.
I also tried with regular expressions, but cannot seem to find the right formula.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: You might want to split your files in two, and have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071114/rename-part-of-file-name-based-on-exact-match-in-contents-of-another-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using text editor **Notepad++** as I'm using text editor **UltraEdit**.

An **UltraEdit** macro solution for this task would be:

```
InsertMode
ColumnModeOff
HexOff
Top
PerlReOn
Loop 0
Find MatchCase RegExp "^[ \t]*(\w+\.text)[ \t]*=[ \t]*("[^\r\n]+)\r?\n([\s\S]+?)\.tag([ \t]*=[ \t]*)\1"
Replace All "\3\4\2"
IfNotFound
ExitLoop
EndIf
EndLoop
```

I explain the Perl regular expression Replace All executed on the entire file content in a loop until nothing could be replaced anymore. This Perl regular expression Replace All should work also in **Notepad++**.

`^` ... start every search at beginning of a line.

`[ \t]*` ... 0 or more spaces or tabs can be at beginning of a line.

`\w+` ... find a string with 1 or more word characters which are letters, digits and the character underscore.

`\.text` ... next the fixed string **.text** must be in the line.

The opening and closing parenthesis around `\w+\.text` mark/capture the string found by this expression for backreferencing. This part of the found string is backreferenced in search string itself with `\1`.

`[ \t]*=[ \t]*` ... next there can be 0 or more spaces or tabs before an equal sign must be found and again 0 or more spaces or tabs are found.

`("[^\r\n]+)` ... finds a string starting with a double quote and ending at end of the line which is also captured for backreferencing. This expression matches the text value and also a comment if present. This part of the found string is backreferenced in replace string with `\2`.

`\r?\n` ... next a carriage return if present and a line feed is matched.

The expression up to `\n` matches therefore the text definition line.

`([\s\S]+?)` ... a non greedy expression matching anything up to the position on which the next part of the expression returns a positive result. This expression matches everything from beginning of line below the current line with a text value definition to end of name of the matching tag value variable. For example on first run for **label1.text** this expression matches everything from **label2.text** to **ledfan**. This block is also captured for backreferencing in replace string with `\3`.

`\.tag` ... the fixed string `.tag` must be found next.

`([ \t]*=[ \t]*)` ... next there can be 0 or more spaces or tabs before an equal sign must be found and again 0 or more spaces or tabs are found. This part of the found string is captured for backreferencing with `\4` in the replace string.

`\1` ... the name of the text value variable must be finally found, too.

---

I must add that this macro respectively Perl regular expression Replace All executed in a loop until nothing could be replaced anymore works only if every text value is assigned only once to a variable. If a text value like **label2.text** would be assigned twice to a variable, this solution would not work.

An **UltraEdit** macro solution working also with multiple assignments of a text value to a variable would be:

```
InsertMode
ColumnModeOff
HexOff
Top
UltraEditReOn
Clipboard 9
Loop 0
Find MatchCase RegExp "%[^t ]++[0-9A-Za-z_]+.text[^t ]++=[^t ]++""
IfNotFound
ExitLoop
EndIf
Key LEFT ARROW
Find MatchCase RegExp ""*$"
Copy
Key HOME
Find MatchCase RegExp "[0-9A-Za-z_]+.text"
Find MatchCase RegExp ".tag^([^t ]++=[^t ]++^)^s"
Replace All "^1^c"
DeleteLine
EndLoop
ClearClipboard
Clipboard 0
```

But this macro uses content of user clipboard 9 (`^c`) and the currently selected text (`^s`) in an UltraEdit regular expression Replace All which cannot be done with the other regular expression engines (Unix and Perl) supported by **UltraEdit**.

Another advantage of this solution is the deletion of lines defining a text value not assigned to any other variable in the code below. So this macro performs also a cleanup of unused text values.

I don't know how to use this method in a **Notepad++** macro as I'm not using **Notepad++**.

---

The first solution working only with only 1 assignment of a text variable to another variable using a Perl regular expression Replace All could be also executed with *Replace in Files* command to run it on all files of a directory (tree), of course also in a loop until nothing could be replaced anymore in any file.

---

The **UltraEdit** macros for the next task requested with a comment to change

```
txtOssigeno.temp = GetStringResource(167)
txtFotoresistenza.temp = GetStringResource(174)
Me.txtOssigeno.Caption = Prot00026
Me.txtFotoresistenza.Caption =Prot00006
```

into

```
GetStringResource(167) = Prot00026
GetStringResource(174) = Prot00006
```

are with Perl regular expression engine:

```
InsertMode
ColumnModeOff
HexOff
Top
PerlReOn
Loop 0
Find MatchCase RegExp "^[ \t]*(\w+)\.temp[ \t]*=[ \t]*([\w()]+)[^\r\n]*?\r?\n([\s\S]+?)Me\.\1\.Caption[ \t]*=[ \t]*"
Replace All "\3\2 = "
IfNotFound
ExitLoop
EndIf
EndLoop
```

and with UltraEdit regular expression engine:

```
InsertMode
ColumnModeOff
HexOff
Top
UltraEditReOn
Clipboard 9
Loop 0
Find MatchCase RegExp "%[^t ]++[0-9A-Za-z_]+.temp[^t ]++="
IfNotFound
ExitLoop
EndIf
Find MatchCase RegExp "[0-9A-Za-z_()]+"
Copy
Key HOME
Find MatchCase RegExp "[0-9A-Za-z_]+"
Find MatchCase RegExp "Me.^s.Caption[^t ]++=[^t ]++"
Replace All "^c = "
DeleteLine
EndLoop
ClearClipboard
Clipboard 0
```

It is up to you which one of the 2 macros you want to use.

Comment: Perfect... Now I want to change te variabile example:

Comment: Perfect... Now I want to change te variabile example:
`
txtOssigeno.temp = GetStringResource(167)
txtFotoresistenza.temp = GetStringResource(174)
    
        Me.txtOssigeno.Caption = Prot00026
        Me.txtFotoresistenza.Caption =Prot00006
`
into:
`
GetStringResource(167) = Prot00026
GetStringResource(174) = Prot00006
`
I try 
Find `^[ \t]*(\w+)\.temp[ \t]*=[ \t]*(GetStringResource[^\r\n]+)\r?\n([\s\S]+?)\Me.\1.Caption` 
and
Replce \2
but not work What's wrong?

Comment: Your regular expression works also for the find part. The mistake is in the replace string as you would need with your expression `\3\2` to keep the lines between the line to remove and the line to update. I updated my answer also with 2 new macros for this new task.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, you can do it for one variable at a time. If you run the replacement repeatedly, you can do all the lines. Maybe you can do that with a macro.

Here is a regex that will work for one variable (one pair of lines):

Search: `(?sm)^(\w+)\.[^=]*(=.*?[\r\n]+)(.*)^(\w+)\.tag[^=]*=\s*\1[^\r\n]*`

Replace: `\3\4\2`